# E2108 Improper use of typedef 'TJSONObject' Error when using GetValue path evaluator

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I cannot use path evaluator with GetValue.

This is the situation:

```json
[{"source":"aaaa","cluster":"1","tokens":[{},{}]}, {"source":"bbbb","cluster":"2","tokens":[{},{}]}]
```

```cpp
TJSONArray *Data = ...;

TJSONObject *obj;
TJSONPair *jpa;

for(int i=0; i<Data->Size(); i++)
{
  obj = (TJSONObject*) Data->Get(i); 
  jpa = obj->GetValue<TJSONObject>("$.tokens");
}
```

I got an error, on this line:

```cpp
jpa = obj->GetValue<TJSONObject>("$["+IntToStr(i)+"].tokens");
```

> ERROR:
>   E2108 Improper use of typedef 'TJSONObject'

How to use path evaluator correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tokens` field is an Array, not an Object.  So you need to request a `TJSONArray` from `GetValue<T>()` instead of a `TJSONObject`.

But, more importantly, the type you request from `GetValue<T>()` needs to be a *pointer* type since you are requesting a JSON class type, and not a built-in type like an `int` or `String`.  Since you are requesting a `TJSONObject` instead of a `TJSONObject*`, that is why you are getting the error.

Also, `GetValue<T>()` returns the *value* portion of a Pair, not the Pair itself.  So you need to assign the returned pointer to a `TJSONArray*` variable (`jpa` is a `TJSONPair*` instead).

Try this:

```
TJSONArray *Data = ...;

TJSONObject *obj;
TJSONArray *arr;

for(int i = 0; i < Data->Size(); i++)
{
    obj = (TJSONObject*) Data->Get(i);
    arr = obj->GetValue<TJSONArray*>("tokens");
}
```

Or:

```
TJSONArray *Data = ...;

TJSONArray *arr;

for(int i = 0; i < Data->Size(); i++)
{
    arr = Data->GetValue<TJSONArray*>("$["+IntToStr(i)+"].tokens");
}
```